# MySQL Date_Format with Month() in query

Tags: mysql

I need to extract the `month` from the `date` in the database but I need to format it to became a *word-written month*.

**Sample Date in the Database**

```
2017-11-22
```

**Month Query**

```
SELECT MONTH(createdAt) FROM tbltest
```

The output of this is the *numerical* `month` of the `createdAt` ex: **11**

**Month with Date_Format Query**  <----- *not working*

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MONTH(createdAt), '%Y-%b-%d') as title
FROM tbltest
```

**Output that I am looking for**

```
Nov
```

Comment: pls share exact output you want to show

Comment: added thanks. ffrom the sample `2017-11-22` will extract the month resulting to `Nov`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try MONTHNAME function

```
    SELECT MONTHNAME(createdAt) FROM tbltest
```

For short month name you can use

```
    select DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%b') from tbltest
```

Comment: it is working thanks. but I want the short month name. ex: `november` = `nov`

Comment: I update answer for short month name. You can check it, one more thing you are using wrong of date_format because you pass MONTH(createdAt), you should pass createdAt as parameter only

Comment: thanks. I am not aware that the `DATE_FORMAT()` is possible to use only for month. I always using it for full date format. anyway thanks. marked as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(createdAt, '%b') as monthShortName
FROM tbltest;
```

Pls refer : https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php